# unity 2D - how to jump by dragging up the finger on touch screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first of all, sorry for my bad English.
i am making a game based on unity 2D engine and using C# language ... i have a problem with my touch system and i can not solve it.now i have a key for jump but it is not the way that i want for jumping. i just wanna make my player jump when the finger touched the screen and dragging up. 
here is my code :

```
// GUI textures
public GUITexture guiLeft;
public GUITexture guiRight;
public GUITexture guiJump;

// Movement variables
public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public float jumpForce = 50f;
public float maxJumpVelocity = 2f;

// Movement flags
private bool moveLeft, moveRight, doJump = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    // Check to see if the screen is being touched
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        // Get the touch info
        Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);

        // Did the touch action just begin?
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            // Are we touching the left arrow?
            if (guiLeft.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touching Left Control");
                moveLeft = true;
            }

            // Are we touching the right arrow?
            if (guiRight.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touching Right Control");
                moveRight = true;
            }

            // Are we touching the jump button?
            if (guiJump.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touching Jump Control");
                doJump = true;
            }
        }

        // Did the touch end?
        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            // Stop all movement
            doJump = moveLeft = moveRight = false;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

    // Is the left mouse button down?
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // Are we clicking the left arrow?
        if (guiLeft.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Left Control");
            moveLeft = true;
        }

        // Are we clicking the right arrow?
        if (guiRight.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Right Control");
            moveRight = true;
        }

        // Are we clicking the jump button?
        if (guiJump.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Jump Control");
            doJump = true;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        // Stop all movement on left mouse button up
        doJump = moveLeft = moveRight = false;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Set velocity based on our movement flags.
    if (moveLeft)
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = -Vector2.right * moveSpeed;
    }

    if (moveRight)
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.right * moveSpeed;
    }

    if (doJump)
    {
        // If we have not reached the maximum jump velocity, keep applying force.
        if (rigidbody2D.velocity.y < maxJumpVelocity)
        {
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        } else {
            // Otherwise stop jumping
            doJump = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.

It will give which direction you moved your hand by each update.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more state for touch inputs not only start and end. If I remember correctly, it is TouchPhase.Moved. So first thing you should do is, get the touch position when touch starts.(TouchPhase.Began), after that you need to check the touch position every frame(TouchPhase.Moved). Than you will have 2 touch position which are starting and current positions. So lets say if difference between these two x cooridinates bigger than something(Depends what kind of sensivity you want), you can call the jump function or what else you want.